# Adding subframes in Tkinter python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to dynamically add subframes to a main Frame widget. The subframes are columns with buttons in them, I created a separate class for the subframes in order to have the subframes as objects in a list so I can alter them later. In reality the amount of extra columns also depends on user input.

I first use the grid manager to add widgets to the main Frame, later I use grid to add buttons to the subframes. I expect grid to realize when it is used in different frames, but it appears the grid calls inside the subframe class place widgets directly inside the main frame instead of just inside the subframe.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

extra_columns = 1

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(sticky="nsew")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (MainFrame,):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("MainFrame")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.subframes = []
        self.init_main()
        self.init_subframes()

    def init_main(self):
        self.title = tk.Label(text='Title')
        self.title.grid(row=0, column = 2)
        for i in range(1, 3):
            b = tk.Button(text=str(i))
            b.grid(row=i, column=0)
            c = tk.Button(text=str(i+10))
            c.grid(row=i, column=2+extra_columns+1)

    def init_subframes(self):
        for i in range(1, extra_columns+1):
            m = SubFrame(self)
            self.subframes.append(m)
            m.grid(row=1, column=2+i, rowspan=5)


class SubFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        for i in range(1, 6):
            b = tk.Button(text="extra"+str(i), command=lambda: print("button \
pressed"))
            b.grid(row=i, column=0)


root = App()
root.mainloop()
```

For the record: the way I'm displaying the main frame (inside the App class) is taken from a tutorial on pythonprogramming.net and is also used in my real code.

Thanks!

Comment: are you aware that the first argument to `Label`, `Button`, etc, is the parent window or frame which should contain the label or button?

Comment: Thanks, adding master=... to all my grid assignments solved my issues!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46992457/adding-subframes-in-tkinter-python3/46996246#comment80932675_46992457), when creating a widget(frame, button, label etc.) object, unless a frame object explicitly is passed as parent, root window is assumed to be the parent.

If you want to manage geometry on a frame basis you need to assign the widget's parent as that frame.

Check the code below:

```
import tkinter as tk

#creates a window object named root, this object is the default parent for ever widget object
root = tk.Tk()

#creates a frame that is a child of object named 'root'
mainFrame = tk.Frame(master=root)

#creates a frame that is a child of 'mainFrame'
subFrame_mainFrame = tk.Frame(mainFrame)

#creates a button that is a child of 'subFrame'
button_subFrame_mainFrame_root = tk.Button(master=subFrame)

#creates a button that is a child of default, which is 'root' in this case
button_root = tk.Button()

#creates a button that is a child of mainFrame
button_mainFrame = tk.Button(mainFrame)
```

You *can* manage the geometry of a frame's content independent of main window or whatever, given that you correctly assigned the frame's children to it as parent.

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/179067/152065)'s an example on managing geometry modularly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed example, I added master=self as a parameter to every grid call and all children get aligned correctly!

Comment: @CelThys for reference you don't actually need to say `master=` as the first parameter of every widget is assumed to be the widget's parent or "master". Just saying `Button(parent, text=........)` is good enough.